# Dropzone.js fade on removeFile()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js and my "remove when it's finished" code looks like this:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
     init: function () {
        this.on("success", function (file) {
           this.removeFile(file);
        });
     }
};
```

It works as expected, but the section is removed instantly. What I'd like is for that to take a second and fade out so that the user can actually see that the image completed before it's gone. How can I add some kind of transition to removeFile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With jQuery, should be something like this...

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  init: function () {
    this.on("success", function (file) {
      var _this = this;
      $(file.previewElement).fadeOut({
        complete: function() {
          // If you want to keep track internally...
          _this.removeFile(file);
        }
      });
    });
  }
};
```